# Memory assignement for Map<String,List<String>>

Tags: java, hashmap

When we do `Map<String,List<String>> = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();`
it creates an empty map but is the `List` inside the map empty as well or is it a null value?

Comment: There are no `List`s inside the `Map`. It's empty. If you call `get` on it, any argument value will return `null`.

Comment: When you instantiate a collection, it is empty. Any initial capacity it has are of `null` values, so there are no `List`s in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so too but needed to confirm just in case

Comment: @Zircon do you have a source from where I could verify it?

Comment: And just one more thing to clarify: the idea of the map is that you have **multiple** string keys, each one coming with its own list. Your question somehow implies that you really should study the collections a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
Map<String,List<String>> = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

pertains only to the instantiation of a parameterized HashMap.  You are using generics to enforce generic types, which states that the TYPE for key must be a String and the TYPE value must be a `List<String>`.  There is no `List<String>` in memory until you begin adding separately created `List<String>` objects into to your map.  This would look like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();//BTW, You only need to parameterize the object declaration since Java 7

List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Betty");
names.add("Bob");
names.add("Jessica");
names.add("Jim");
myMap.put("names", names);//Where "names" is your key and names is your value.
```

You can proceed to continue adding more lists to your map from there.

Answer (score 1):

To a certain degree, this depends on the collection type you are using. A hashmap or hashset will not allocate any space for objects that will potentially be added later on. So you only carry the "cost" for exactly that one map or set object when creating it.

Whereas for ArrayList, that is different - they are created using an initial *capacity* (10 by default); meaning that creating an `ArrayList<String>` will allocate for an array of strings (`String[10]` in that sense). So, `HashMap<String, List<String>>` is "cheaper" than `List<Map<Whatever, NotOfInterest>>`.

On the other hand: this is really not something to worry about. Unless you are working in "embedded computing" (or you are dealing with millions of objects all the time), you should much more worry about good OO designs instead of memory (or performance) cost of java collections.

Comment: Eh?  A `String[10]` filled with null will take exactly the same amount of memory as a `SuperMassiveObject[10]` filled with null.  They both store references, not the objects themselves, and all references are equally sized.

Comment: Sure. But an array for 10 items is created. That is the whole point!

Comment: I am using this empty map and storing results of some computation in it. But there is a chance that if some condition is not satisfied empty map would be returned as is. The problem arises here: I need to use streams on this returned map, but if the map is empty I need to make sure List<String> inside this map is not null otherwise streams would fail

Comment: "I need to make sure List<String> inside this map is not null otherwise streams would fail" - This is only true if you insert `null` as the value for a key. You can avoid this by using a `LinkedHashMap` which does not allow null values. Then, even if the `Map` is empty, any stream operations will simply do nothing because there are no elements to iterate over.

Comment: @Zircon Checked in javadoc - "This class provides all of the optional Map operations, and permits null elements"
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer: When you instantiate a collection, it is empty. Any initial capacity it has are of null values, so there are no Lists in this case. – Zircon

Comment: You probably want to refer to the source of this